# NoSuchElementException and more

Tags: java, loops

My assignment is:

- Create a file that has 2 columns of numbers: *Distance* and *Speed*.
- Write a class `TravelInfo` which has three pieces of information: *Speed*, *Time*, *Distance*.
- The class should also have a method `calcTime()` which calculates the time it will take to reach a destination based on the distance and speed (recall: Time = Distance/Speed)
- Write a main program that:

  - Creates an ArrayList of `TravelInfo` objects of size 10.
  - Prompts the user for the name of the file and reads the data into `TravelInfo` objects
  - Calls the `calcTime()` method on each `TravelInfo` object.
  - Creates an output file with the data written in the format: *Distance, Time, Speed*

Every time I run my program I get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Other than this error I think I have done everything right except maybe calling my method, and I still haven't formatted the output file yet (not quite sure how). I can't continue while I get this error.

Here is my `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<TravelInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("What is the name of the file?");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
    File f = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
    while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
        int s = inputFile.nextInt();
        int d = inputFile.nextInt();
        int t = inputFile.nextInt();


        TravelInfo p = new TravelInfo(s, d, t);
        list.add(p);
        TravelInfo cls = new TravelInfo(s,d,t);
        cls.calcTime(t);
        cls.calcTime(s);
        cls.calcTime(d);

       // System.out.println("Time is " + cls.calcTime(t));

       /*for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
           list.get(i).print();
      */ }
        for(TravelInfo k : list)
            System.out.println(k);

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Data.txt");
        outputFile.println(list);
        //outputFile.println();
        outputFile.close();
    }

}
```

And my `TravelInfo` class

```
public class TravelInfo {
    private int speed;
    private int distance;
    private int time;

    public TravelInfo(int s, int d, int t) {
        speed = s;
        distance = d;
        time = t;
    }
    public int calcTime(int time) {
        time = distance/speed;
        return time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which scanner throws the exception? I assume it's the file one

Comment: I think both but i'm not really sure

Comment: It's gotta be one or the other. Can we see the full stack trace?

Comment: Sorry what's a full stack trace? I'm new to programming so i'm not sure what that is

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Most likely, the file you're trying to parse is in a wrong format - input is exhausted.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at cw7_3.CW7_3.main(CW7_3.java:31)
C:\Users\bambo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: You ran out of file to read

Comment: What does that mean exactly? My file is a.txt file called numbers and in it I just have two rows of 5 numbers

Comment: Five numbers? You're reading three numbers on each iteration. Five isn't divideable by three.

Comment: oh okay, i changed it to 6 and it ran properly and created the data file with my output but for some reason this was what was printed: cw7_3.TravelInfo@42a57993
cw7_3.TravelInfo@75b84c92
cw7_3.TravelInfo@6bc7c054
cw7_3.TravelInfo@232204a1

Comment: Well, what did you expect? In ´System.out.println(k)´, Java uses the default output for Objects. You mught want to override the `TravelInfo.toString()` method.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You shall do some more validation, and never use the `nextXXX()` methods blindly - something like

```
while(true)
{
    if (!inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
       System.err.println("Reading file failed - invalid format (s)");
       break;
    }
    int s = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Reading s = " + s);

    if (!inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
       System.err.println("Reading file failed - invalid format (d)");
       break;
    }
    int d = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Reading d = " + d);


    if (!inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
       System.err.println("Reading file failed - invalid format (t)");
       break;
    }
    int t = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Reading t = " + t);
    // Do some stuff
}
```

This way, you will avoid the `NoSuchElementException`, and the application will terminate gracefully. You will get the debugging output on the console. It will also print out what exactly has been read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

As Dorian said, you're missing some validation:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()) // Tells you there is "at least" 1 more element.
{
    int s = inputFile.nextInt();   // Good
    int d = inputFile.nextInt();   // Not good if 's' has taken the last element
    int t = inputFile.nextInt();   // Same as above

    // rest of the code here...
}
```

I personnally don't like the 'while(true)' stuff, so here is my version.

```
while(inputFile.hasNextInt())  // I would use 'hasNextInt()' rather than 'hasNext()'
                               // This will make sure the next data can be cast to an Integer
{
    Integer d = null;
    Integer t = null;
    Integer s = inputFile.nextInt();

    if( inputFile.hasNextInt() {
        d = inputFile.nextInt();
        if( inputFile.hasNextInt() {
            t = inputFile.nextInt();
        }
    }

    // 's' will never be null.
    if( d != null && t != null ) {
        TravelInfo p = new TravelInfo(s, d, t);
        list.add(p);
        TravelInfo cls = new TravelInfo(s,d,t);
        cls.calcTime(t);
        cls.calcTime(s);
        cls.calcTime(d);

       // System.out.println("Time is " + cls.calcTime(t));

       /*for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
       {
           list.get(i).print();
      */ }
        for(TravelInfo k : list)
            System.out.println(k);

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Data.txt");
        outputFile.println(list);
        //outputFile.println();
        outputFile.close();
    }
    else if( inputFile.hasNext()) {
        // At this point, you there the remaining data cannot be safely cast to an Integer.
    }
    else {
       // Not enough data to process.
    }
}

public class TravelInfo {
    private int speed;
    private int distance;
    private int time;

    public TravelInfo(int s, int d, int t) {
        speed = s;
        distance = d;
        time = t;
    }
    public int calcTime(int time) {
        time = distance/speed;
        return time;
    }

    // Override toString() instead of using the default Object.toString()
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Return whatever 'String' you want
        return String.format( "%d, %d, %d", speed, distance, time );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and am still getting the same output of [cw7_3.TravelInfo@42a57993 like 20 times

Comment: @Nitro What is your expected output? `System.out.println(k);` is the same as `System.out.println( k.toString());`. Since you don't override `toString()`, it calls `Object.toString()`